# Angular2 *ngFor Dropdown with filter initial value is empty

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-pipe

**Hi, I am creating two dropdown one for display month and another for display day. when user select month, the day dropdown change to 30 or 31 based on which month. I achieve this using custom filter pipe apply in day dropdown option. But However when user select month the initial day dropdown option is empty. I given my code in below**

*month DropDown:*

```
 <option *range="['month']; let num">{{num}}</option>
```

Note:

> *range is my own directive for display month option like *ngFor

its display as

```
<option>Jan</option>

<option>Feb</option> .........
```

*Day DropDown:*

```html
 <select formControlName="day" >
     <option>Select Day</option> 
     <option *ngFor="let number of calendar |      dayFilter:register.controls['dob'].controls['month'].value" >{{number.day}}</option>
</select>
```

DayFilter:

And My Custom Filter for day filtering when user select month:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name : 'dayFilter'
})
export class DayFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value:any, filter: any): any{
     var result;
      if(filter === 'April' || filter === 'june' || filter === 'september' || filter === 'november' ){     
        for(const item of value)
        {             
           result = value.filter(items=> items['day']< 31);
        }
               return result;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

**The Problem is:**

> When Page loads intially it works fine with default dropdown selected option is Select Day.
>
> The problem is when i selecting month like April.. The defult value in
>   the day dropdown is empty instead of select day.
>   [image]

When Page loads intially:[it works fine][see the month and Day]
When user select April the Day dropdown as empty:
[image]